# How to order X axis labels using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a large dataset with many years of data. For some unknown reason my facet_wrap()
function is printing the X axis labels on every single graph when it should be showing
only the X axis labels of the bottom graph. Consider the below small dataset with only
two years of data to illustrate what I am talking about. The attached graphic should show
X axis labels only for 1999, however, 1998 is also showing the X axis labels (it shouldn't be).

```
library(tidyverse)
mydat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(10592, 10957, 10623, 10988, 
10651, 11017, 10682, 11048, 10712, 11078, 10743, 11109, 10773, 
11139, 10804, 11170, 10835, 11201, 10500, 10865, 10531, 10896, 
10561, 10926), class = "Date"), year = c(1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 
1999L, 1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 1999L, 
1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 1999L, 1998L, 
1999L, 1998L, 1999L), Salinity = c(3.72393939393939, 0.728227272727273, 
0.876969696969697, 0.574393939393939, 0.523409090909091, 0.240893939393939, 
0.341681818181818, 0.211287878787879, 0.318651515151515, 0.325166666666667, 
0.272969696969697, 1.0430303030303, 0.282242424242424, 2.06519696969697, 
0.481469696969697, 2.89651515151515, 0.849787878787879, 4.13565151515152, 
6.51239393939394, 0.965257575757576, 5.53680303030303, 1.8145, 
4.77318181818182, 1.58481818181818)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))

 mydat
#Create graphic
ggplot(mydat,aes(date,Salinity)) +
 geom_line(size=.8) +
 scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",date_labels = "%b",expand=c(0,0.5)) +
 theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
 facet_wrap(~year,ncol=1,scale="free_x") + ggtitle("test")
```

Notice the X axis labels on the upper graphic

[image]

`A contributor - @LC-datascientist - suggested that I add '1111' to the 'date' column like so:`

```
mydat %>% mutate(date = as.Date(gsub("\\d{4}", "1111", date))) %>%
 ggplot(aes(date,Salinity)) +
 geom_line(size=.8) +
 scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",date_labels = "%b",expand=c(0,0.5)) +
 theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
 facet_wrap(~year,ncol=1) + ggtitle("test")
```

This nice trick to the date column gets rid of the unwanted X axis labels in the 1998 panel,
however, it switches my bottom graph labels from Oct to Sept to Jan to Dec (graphic below).

[image]

`Question: How do I order the X axis labels back to show from Oct to Dec?`

**EDITED: THIS IS THE GRAPHIC I AM GETTING WITH THE LARGER DATASET.**

```
 library(readxl)
 library(tidyverse)
 mydat <- read_excel("s98_99.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")
mydat %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(date = format(date, '%b'),
         date = factor(date, unique(date))) %>%
ggplot(aes(date,Salinity, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size=.8) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  facet_wrap(~year,ncol=1) + 
  ggtitle("test")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this -

Extract the month from date, change the x-axis to factor with levels assigned based on ascending order of dates and plot the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydat %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(date = format(date, '%b'),
         date = factor(date, unique(date))) %>%
ggplot(aes(date,Salinity, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size=.8) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  facet_wrap(~year,ncol=1) + 
  ggtitle("test")
```

[image]

---

For the updated dataset you may want to summarise the result first.

```
mydat <- readxl::read_excel("s98_99.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")

mydat %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month, unique(month))) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(WYR, month) %>%
  summarise(Salinity = mean(Salinity)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month,Salinity, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size=.8) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  facet_wrap(~WYR,ncol=1) + 
  ggtitle("test")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected with this small dataset. However, I can't make it work with a larger dataset. Do you mind trying this dataset from here: https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6b678b59666fa57269 You can just copy and paste the code I used from here `mydat <- read_excel("s98_99.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")
mydat %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(date = format(date, '%b'),
         date = factor(date, unique(date))) %>%
ggplot(aes(date,Salinity, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size=.8) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  facet_wrap(~year,ncol=1)`

Comment: I edited my question above and included the graphic and code I used with my larger dataset. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Salvador I think you should summarise the result first in your actual data. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Ronak_Shah It does work well when grouping `group_by(WYR, month)`, Thanks. I also need to group by Box `group_by(WYR, month,Box)`. and `colour=Box.` When I add Box to the group it returns a weird graph.